# Custom theme is not working in IOS for flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, colors, themes

I have created a custom theme in flutter app. It working fine in android but have only violate color in ios. I tried but nothing is changed.

main.dart

```
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:newflutter/ui_helper/theme_const.dart';
import 'package:newflutter/views/decider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // await Upgrader.clearSavedSettings();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

  await GetStorage.init();
  final localMemory = GetStorage();
  bool? isDarkTheme = localMemory.read('isDark');
  localMemory.write('isFirstTimeHome', true);

  runApp(MyApp(
    isDarkTheme: isDarkTheme,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? isDarkTheme;
  const MyApp({super.key, this.isDarkTheme});

  get camera => null;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isDarkTheme == null || isDarkTheme == true
        ? SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
            systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
            systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.black,
            systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          ))
        : null;

    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    
      themeMode: isDarkTheme == null || isDarkTheme == true
          ? ThemeMode.light
          : ThemeMode.dark,
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,

      home: UpgradeAlert(upgrader: Upgrader(), child: const Decider()),
    );
  }
}
```

theme file

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Define your custom primary color
MaterialColor customPrimaryColor = const MaterialColor(
  0xFF10489B,
  <int, Color>{
    50: Color(0xFFss10489B),
    100: Color(0xFF10489B),

    800: Color(0xFFss10489B),
    900: Color(0xFF10ss489B),
  },
);

ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: customPrimaryColor,
  primaryColorDark: Colors.indigoAccent,
  primaryColorLight: const Color(0xffC3D8FB),

  fontFamily: 'Mulish',
  brightness: Brightness.light,

  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    displayLarge: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontFamily: 'Mulish-Bold',
      fontSize: 22,
      color: Color(0xff000000),
    ),

    headlineSmall: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      fontFamily: 'Mulish-Bold',
      fontSize: 16,
      color: Color(0xff000000),
    ),
    
  ),

);

ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  //primarySwatch: Colors.red,
  primaryColorDark: const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 39, 39),
  primaryColorLight: const Color(0xff444444),
  cardTheme: const CardTheme(elevation: 0),
  fontFamily: 'Mulish',
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    displayLarge: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontFamily: 'Mulish-Bold',
      fontSize: 22,
      color: Color(0xffffffff),
    ),

    headlineSmall: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      fontFamily: 'Mulish-Bold',
      fontSize: 16,
      color: Color(0xffffffff),
    ),

  ),

);
```

Please check this one and let me know if anyone find issue. Thankx in advance. please see this once. I have added theme file and main.dart file also

Comment: Screenshots? Version of Flutter used to run on Android and on iOS?

Comment: Using >  Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9) and not working in any IOS simulator as well as real ios device. The color code is like dark blue but the same theme or color is looking like violate in ios.